# How to obtain an Edmunds API key?

Tags: api-key

This is my first attempt to use an API. I followed the instructions for registering for an Edmunds API (http://developer.edmunds.com/).
I registered for an account, got an email from them to confirm, clicked on that link, and got a request to register my application, which I filled out.
But when I log into my account and click on "keys", all I get is the message "You don't have any keys yet".

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey.. did you find any solution for this.. i am facing the same problem.. and i dont know from where to get api key..

Comment: @Kriti hey.. did you find any solution for this.. i am facing the same problem.. and i dont know from where to get api key

Comment: @nasty no... i still didnt get any key. so i ended up using http://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/ in my project

Comment: @Kriti does it support Australian models?

Comment: well i didnt checked it specifically for australian models.. but if you can tell me any make and model.. i can check it for you. :)

Comment: Awesome. Can you check if they have "2010 > Mazda > 3 (or Mazda3) and give me the models they show. Also check 2001 > Subaru > Liberty and the models. Thanks heaps  @Kriti

Comment: you can check the json response from https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getmodelsformakeyear/make/mazda/modelyear/2010?format=json for mazda. :)

Comment: Thanks. But it doesnt show the styles under "Mazda3". There should be a style called NEO

Comment: Sorry @Kriti Do you know how to get the styles to show up?

Comment: @nasty actually i just need make and model for my project. so i dont know how you can get style from models...

Answer (score 14):

### Here is the email response I got from Edmunds:

> Joe,
>
> Thank you for your interest in the Edmunds Open API Program.
>
> Unfortunately, we are in the process of retiring our Open API Program. Therefore, we are unable to issue you an API key at this time.
>
> Regards,
> Edmunds

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

The Edmunds API has been shutdown.

I would like to also recommend this [website](http://auto.stack.network/apis/), it contains a list of the latest car information/database APIs.

---

I can't remember exactly how I created mine, I believe I created my dev account and then received an api key link via email. I clicked the link and it took me to a page where I could setup my app and receive an api key. You should have received said email by now.

If that doesn't work then try emailing: api@edmunds.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What happened after you filled out your app registration? How did you receive the key?  I tried emaiiling api@edmunds.com and didn't receive a reply. Thanks.

Comment: @AsyaTakken I received an email with the details (and a link to my dev app page). If you haven't received said email after registering an application, then simply send them an email.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff is it compulsory that our app needs to be live at play store or app store to get api key?

Comment: @Kriti Nope, otherwise how an earth would test the api to make sure it works. I got my API key before launching my app on the app store. You just have to email them.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Edmunds API would be Marketcheck Cars API

The developer portal is given [here](https://www.marketcheck.com)  with Comprehensive API [documentation](https://apidocs.marketcheck.com)

The APIs supported are

- Inventory Search API
- VIN History API
- Dealers API
- VIN Decoder API
- CRM Cleanse API

and lots more APIs coming up like - Market APIs with active and historical market averages, trends, dealer sales stats, dealer ranking, deal ranking, total cost to own, car market values (like Edmunds TMV) coming up